# How do you pass a string into a c# dll from a c++ dll?

Tags: c#, c++, string, type-conversion, marshalling

I have a c# dll that takes a string as a parameter.  I need to call it from a c++ dll.  i can not figure out what type to pass in from c++ that will convert to a string. Here is an example.

c++ code

```
public:void CreateKey(wchar_t* sName, wchar_t* sValue)
        {           
            API::API::CreateKey(*sName, *sValue); //this is the call to c# where it errors
            return;
        }
    };
```

c# code

```
public static void CreateKey(string sName, string sValue)
{
    DoThing());
}
```

Assume all namespacing and such is correct.  This only appears to be an issue with types between libraries.

When I build this my error is 'error C2664: cannot convert parameter 1 from 'wchar_t' to 'System::String'

in place of wchar_t i have tried WCHAR, char*, LPCSTR, BSTR, all the same error.

Comment: Why are you dereferencing the pointers? That gives you only a single character instead of the entire string

Comment: I am not very strong with c++.  Could you elaborate?

Comment: `*sName` is a single `wchar_t`. But you want a string, which is usually an array of characters with a `\0` as the final character. Also this seems to be some form of C++/CLI or C++/CX, so you probably need to explicitly construct the `System::String`

Comment: You would need to pass the string size as well. Here is a sample
https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/184183/Unmanaged-c-to-managed-c-dll-calls-passing-strings

Comment: Could you elaborate more? how would I explicitly construct a system::string?

Comment: i tried like the sample linked, but i still get the same error when i have an intptr on the c# side and a char* on the c++.

Comment: perhaps  this can help.  I am following along with the sample below.  The only difference is i am using a string instead of an int. https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/695387/Calling-Csharp-NET-methods-from-unmanaged-C-Cplusp